# Is there a way to add more than one custom Minecraft skin on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I imported a custom Minecraft skin into Minecraft, and I wanted another one in a different slot, but when I imported the second one, the first I imported became the *same skin*.

Is there any way I can add more than one custom skin? I tried searching online already, I found questions similar to this but weren't asking for this *reason*. I don't know if I actually can do this, but I'm pretty sure it is possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to have different custom skins in separate slots. The easiest thing for you to do would be to keep the skins you want in a special folder so they are easy to find when you need them.

Bedrock Edition has limitations on engine capacity, and therefore cannot store multiple different skins for you, outside of created characters or purchased skins.

You could apply to be a community creator, and, if accepted, release your sets of skins for use by the community, and then save those in separate slots, but that is a complex process that isnt guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find anything else about this online so, thanks for helping. :)

Comment: @anon no problem! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped though, so other people can see that it has been answered.

Comment: my phone automatically made an album where all my minecraft skins were stored, so i didn't have to worry about losing them